# How to specify log4j output file when using Gradle tomcatRunWar in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, log4j, gradle

When I run my Spring MVC app from within Eclipse using "gradle tomcatRunWar" I get the below error. The build still completes and Tomcat is launched with my app, but I cannot figure out how to specify the output log file in my log4j.xml. If I specify an absolute path, it works fine. But if I specify a relative path, I always get the error below.

Ideally, I'd want the log file to be created wherever the rest of the build artifacts are created. This works just fine if I copy the WAR to Tomcat's webapps directly and launch it manually.

```
<appender name="R" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- THIS WORKS: <param name="File" value="C:/Users/<username>/ws/project1/logs/mylog.log" /> -->
    <!--- below line doesn't work when launching from Eclipse --> 
    <param name="File" value="mylog.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
    </layout>           
</appender>


log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: mylog.log (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    at com.....config.WebAppInitializer.<clinit>(WebAppInitializer.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Could you try to use an absolute path for mylog.log file? E.g. C:/Users/<username>mylog.log

Comment: Using absolute paths works fine. In the absence of an absolute path, where would Gradle attempt to put this file?